# Copying different columns into one single column from different files and renaming them with the same filename

Tags: awk

I have multiple files each with 5 columns and for each file I would like to stack each row on one another and then rename the files to their original names. Any idea how to proceed with that?
I am using awk to stack the rows:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}' file > newfile
```

And tried something like that to try the whole thing but doesn't work..

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print $i}}' *.data > testfile.tmp  && mv testfile.tmp *.data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GNU `awk`, you can [edit files in-place](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace) with bundled `inplace` library:

```
gawk -i inplace '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' *.data
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly.. but I just realised that I need to stack the columns onto one another rather than the rows and do the same thing. Any help with that?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. This one was about inplace modification. Best is to [close this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and post a new question (if you can't find the answer already on SO).